# Azure resourcechanges missing KeyVault?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-resource-graph

I have to get the history of changes of the key in an Azure KeyVault, like updated expiry date via keyUpdate operation, for example.

Is there any way to get those changes? Are the KeyVault changes even stored by Azure?

Checked the resourcechanges table trough the ResourceGraphManager from the SDK and UI and there are no KeyVault entries at all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Azure CLI,

1. [List of Key Vault keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/key?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-key-list) will return the details of your keys.
2. If you want to see the versions of a key using it's ID fetched from above, [Show key versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/key?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-key-list-versions)
3. Then if you want to see it's attributes, [show key's details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/key?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-key-show)

First make sure you know the name of the Key Vault, have performed an `az login` and set the subscription `az account set -s SUBSCRIPTION_ID`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but basically I need this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/how-to/get-resource-changes?tabs=azure-cli , and seems like the KeyVauls are just not supported.